# Grid auto-layout with different columns widths

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid layout using `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10rem, 1fr));`.

```css
.col-6 {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
.grid_container_prodesc {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10rem, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  justify-content: space-between;       /* since .items have justify-content:inherite*/
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}
textarea {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="grid_container_prodesc">
      <label for="id_descfr" style="width: min-content;">French:</label>
      <div class="w-100">
        <textarea name="descfr" cols="40" rows="10" class="notes_prods" maxlength="100" id="id_descfr"> DRIVER DEL , 40W,100-374V, TLWMU40ABK, TLWMBU40ABK</textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">sdf </div>    
</div>
```

So something like this:

[image]

Then the textarea slides under the label at the given width:

[image]

However, when I do have more room, I'd like the textarea to take up more space, while still preserving the sliding behavior. See this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/logicOnAbstractions/pen/JjyBqER). So basically, I'd like the text area to take up say 3/4 of the col-6, and the label just 1/4.

I need to keep the intermediate div (div.w-100) for error messages to be contained. It doesn't have to stay w-100 though I guess.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you **need** to use the grid display or can it change?

Comment: @Kameron yes I was starting to ask myself that.  Initially wanted to use grid because some users might have pretty small desktop screens, so I kinda wanted the longer labels to be allowed to slide under.

But I guess a solution based instead on flexbox could work, if the overall look remains similar

Answer (score 1):

So if I am understanding your question correctly this is the result you are going for. What I did was ditch the `display: grid;` and change it to a `display: flex;` and add a `flex-direction: column;` so that your `textarea` box is still responsive. I also added a `col-12` within each of your `col-6` to ensure that each child element is using up the *full-width* of each half of the page `(col-6)`.

```css
.col-6 {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid_container_prodesc {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;       /* since .items have justify-content:inherite*/
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

textarea {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 90%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-6">
      <div class="col-12">
         <div class="grid_container_prodesc">
            <label for="id_descfr" style="width: min-content;">French:</label>
            <div class="w-100">
               <textarea name="descfr" cols="40" rows="10" class="notes_prods" maxlength="100" id="id_descfr"> DRIVER DEL , 40W,100-374V, TLWMU40ABK, TLWMBU40ABK</textarea>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-6">sdf </div>
      <div class="col-12">
      <!-- right half -->
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmmm but the preferred display would still be to have the labels inline with the textarea.  The grid display's role (where it is then on top) was just to try to accomodate smaller screens....

But yes, maybe flex is a better approach.

Comment: @logicOnAbstractions would you mind providing a markup image of the look you're going for and I will make adjustments based on that.

Comment: that would be the images in the OP

Comment: @logicOnAbstractions is this the type of behavior you're looking for? https://codepen.io/kameronmayers/pen/RwZYbzB

Comment: Somewhat (though with a larger textarea for size above the media query). Though honestly I don't like media queries, I think they're hacky and hard to manage properly as you scale up..... I ended up using flex instead at the item level, and just using grid for larger chunks.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up dropping the grid approach as mentioned in the comment from Kameron's answer. The core of the issue was that I had text areas containing some sizeable chunks of texts at time, with labels of varying lenghts. They need to be (mostly) inline. I thought I could save space for smaller screens with some adaptable grid layout.

That being said, flexbox is much easier to implement in this case. I can allow say 25/75, it shrinks & grows decently.

Then I still used the grid layouts for larger blocks (in the full layout, I have chunks of similarly displayed elements, so the whole chunks of element slide under the other block instead).

```css
.col-6 {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

.flex_container_labelled_notes {
  display:flex;
 }


.flex_container_labelled_notes {
    display: flex;
}

.flex_container_labelled_notes > label {
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    flex: 1 1 25%;
}
.flex_container_labelled_notes > div {
    padding: 0 0.25rem 0.25rem 0.25rem;
    flex: 3 3 75%;

}


textarea.notes_prods {
    height: 3rem !important;
    max-height: 5rem;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="flex_container_labelled_notes">
        <label for="id_descfr">French:</label>
        <div class="w-100">
          <textarea name="descfr" cols="40" rows="10" class="notes_prods" maxlength="100"                    id="id_descfr">DRIVER DEL , 40W,100-374V, TLWMU40ABK, TLWMBU40ABK</textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```